# Best Altium component practice for resistors, capacitors

Tags: altium

In the past when drawing resistors in Altium schematics, I have only  used "Res3" from the supplied Alitum default library "Miscellaneous Devices.IntLib". For each Res3 I place, I only changed the value and footprint as required. Although the project worked and all the information about values and footprints are shown in a BOM, the disadvantage using this method is tracking previously used components when you need to decide which resistor to use.

In a new project, I have moved to a model where I copy the Altium "Res3" to a new schematic library and modify the value, footprint and power dissipation etc, as I would when adding a new IC. It is also easier to update changes later to the same part in all schematics, add in suppliers etc.

Depending on the situation, I can see there are many different ways to manage Altium components. What is your preferred way / best practice when using resistors and capacitors in schematic sheets where the values differ but other specs are the same - reuse the same component or create a new component in a schematic library?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin this, and to some extent it depends on the size of your teams, but for a small team I favour passives in DbLibs and having effectively unique components for each value/footprint combination (And the libs themselves held in SVN).

The trap with doing it your way is that an incautious 'update from libraries' can stuff you as it resets all the values and footprints!

As with most CAD, time spent up front creating templates and setting up libraries is time very well spent.

Answer (score 1):

All what Dan Mills said is correct, and I have created new libraries in every workplace I have moved to, because the existing ones were badly organised, and hence hard to use.

The best way forward in my opinion is to use Dblibs and create all the part numbers in there, while having only one resistor symbol. 
The advantage of using Dblibs is that you can quickly create a lot of parts with similar part numbers, such as resistors. Last time I chose a series of resistors from Yageo and put the whole value set into the database in the matter of minutes, that was over 9000 different values(E192) and sizes (0201/0402/0603/0805 IPC L,M,N), just because Yageo manufacturing part's number was predictable, and was easy to create that many parts just by creating a simple excel sheet with the sequential numbering. The Excel file can then be imported as a CSV into most databases.

Although an Excel file can be used as the database for Altium, I don't advice using is as Altium will lock it from editing, while it is open.

It is worth spending some time planning the library, because once you have started is really hard to change direction without having holes in the information stored, so take the time to make sure you put into the database all the information you need, but also not too much, which makes creating a part a burden.